# How does a vampire with “Methuselah’s Thirst” get full?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

The Feeding flaw “Methuselah’s Thirst” on page 181 says “Your hunger can only be fully slaked by the blood of supernatural creatures...otherwise, it remains constantly at a minimum of 1.”

Does this replace the usual rule where the only way to “fully slake” hunger is to drain and kill a human being? (p.212) Do they stack? If so, is your hunger dice floor at 2 until you find someone supernatural to drink from? Or do you have to drain a supernatural creature to death to lose your last hunger die?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this replaces the rule where you can only get to hunger 0 by killing someone. Since Methuselah's Thirst therefore supersedes the normal limitation of "draining a human" there is no stacking involved. Luckily there is also nothing about draining in the flaws text, meaning that you don't have to kill a supernatural creature to sake your hunger (Which, with the current meta would be deadly, I'd say).

But: In the flaws text it also says:
"[..]it remains constantly at a minimum of 1. (Or higher, depending on Blood Potency (see p. 215)." [V5, p. 181]

So, blood potency still applies with this, meaning you have to edit the table on page 216 a bit to fit your needs.
The first real change to your minimum Hunger applies at Potency 5 ("Must drain and kill a human to reduce Hunger below 2", [V5, page 216]). So, if you're old enough you're stuck at 2 - or later 3 - Hunger if you don't drink from a supernatural being.

It doesn't matter if you kill a human at all, you don't gain anything from doing so...Though, admitedly, if you're at Potency 5+ you also slake less Hunger per human, so you might need to drain them to gain anything from them at all...

Comment: On what basis do you assert that this is a replacement rather than an addition?  For that matter, on what basis do you assert that it has anything to do with hunger 2/3 at all?  Reducing from 3 to 2 isn't going to "fully slake" anything.  It doesn't seem like Methuselah's Thirst would apply.

Comment: In terms to the first question: Because it couldn't be an addition. How would you drain a human and drink from a supernatural being on the same time? And if it were necessary to diablerize they would surely have said so. To the second: Good point. Might be that draining a human works in that regard and puts you to 1 - would be fair Since draining a human always reduces you to 0 I came to the conclusion it just puts your baseline higher.

Comment: vampires are not the only supernatural creature out there, by a long shot.  Additionally, a simpler reading would be to say "Replace 'human' with 'supernatural creature' for this requirement."

Comment: I tried to replace "human" with "supernatural creature" as good as possible - But simply doing that doesn't fit the flaw. It explicitely only gets exchanced when going to hunger 0. And the flaw text itself points to the fact that a higher blood potency potentially puts you at a higher baseline. " minimum of 1.(Or higher, depending on Blood Potency (see p. 215)." [V5, p. 181]" Or how would you read that sentence?

Comment: Ops, forgot to add: No, they're not. But saying "you have to find and KILL a werewolf/changeling/mage to get to hunger 0" nah. Sure, you can drink from them as well. But that doesn't change that "drinking from supernatural being" replaces "drain someone completely".

Comment: From p376: "Draining a werewolf dry can reduce Hunger to 0 for two vampires if they share the kill" The more I look into this the more it looks like it is intended that hunger 0 can only be reached by killing something.

Comment: I think it's wrong to say that the flaw text replace the hunger text. Either it is possible for everybody to drink supernatural blood to get to hunger 0 without killing them or accessible to none.

Answer (score 2):

*[V5, page 211]: "Only draining a human of blood, thereby killing them, can reduce Hunger to 0."*

RAW states that you can NOT reduce Hunger to 0 from supernatural blod, only from draining and killing a **human**.

If this is true human blood would be more powerful in slaking kindreds thirst than kindred blood as it would be the only way to slake the thirst completly.

*[V5, page 213]: "Feeding from a vampire of at least two levels of Blood Potency higher than the drinker slakes 2 points of Hunger for each point of Hunger gained by the donor."*

This clearly states that kindred blood can be more powerful in slaking Hunger than normal human blood.

*[V5, page 181]: "Flaw: (•) Methuselah’s Thirst. Your Hunger can only be fully slaked by the blood of supernatural creatures."*

RAW if combined with the statement from p.211 means that a kindred with this flaw can never ever slake their hunger completly as supernatural creatures blood just can not do that.

Obviously there is something missing as these statement contradict each other. The Methuselah’s Thirst flaw indicates that it should be possible to fully slake your hunger on supernatural blood, not only for those with the flaw.

So does the statement under Feeding from Other Vampires:
*[V5, page 213]: "A vampire who feeds on another vampire slakes 1 point of their Hunger for each point of increased Hunger they inflict on the donor, willing or unwilling."*

I´d say there is an error in the book as these rules contradicts each other.

**My suggestion for a fix:**

Change the sentence on page 211: "Only draining a human **or a supernatural creature** of blood, thereby killing them, can reduce Hunger to 0."

*Thanks for the comment Marius. Edited my suggested fix to incorporate your advice.*

Comment: *[V5, page 376]: "Draining a werewolf dry can reduce Hunger to 0 for two vampires if they share the kill."* I think this show how the authors intended to solve what you call a contradiction between p211 and the MT flaw.